# #define in Boost Jamfiles

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

This is my project structure:

```
MainFolder
  - Jamroot.jam
  - AnotherFolder
      - libFolder
          - Jamfile.jam
          - cpp files
```

I have an #ifdef in one of the cpp files. 
Example:

```
#ifdef SOMEVALUE
  Code
#endif
```

I need to compile the cpp files with #define in Jamfile. Since, I am having two types of executables (one with #define and one without) I need to do this in Jamfile itself and not cpp code.

I have tried the following, which does not work (unable to find definitions inside #ifdef #endif block):

```
lib libname : [ glob *.cpp ] : <link>static : <define>SOMEVALUE ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a preprocessor definition uses the "define" feature as you've seen given your example. But the feature needs to be specified as a [requirement](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.targets.requirements) of the target definition. The [requirements](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.targets.requirements) are specified as the third argument of the target definition not the fourth as in your use case. Hence instead of:

```
lib
  libname # main-target-name
  : [ glob *.cpp ] # sources
  : <link>static # requirements
  : <define>SOMEVALUE # default-build
  ;
```

You need to move the "<define>" from the usage requirements to the target requirements:

```
lib
  libname # main-target-name
  : [ glob *.cpp ] # sources
  : <link>static <define>SOMEVALUE # requirements
  : # default-build
  : # usage-requirements
  ;
```

You can find what all the arguments to the target definition are [here](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.targets).

Answer (score 0):

In mine earlier project we use to have different compilation for debug mode - which apart from adding debug symbols use to print many usefull values during run time. 
The way it was done

```
#ifdef DEBUG
/* Piece of code here*/
#endif
```

and while compilation via GCC with the -DDEBUG